# read/write access to part of a mount while it is overmounted

Tags: mount

I am setting up a linux machine with a system partition (i.e. mounted at /) and a separate encrypted partition for home ('enchome'). enchome will not be mounted at boot-time but sometime thereafter will be mounted at /home by a script after a user logs in and enters the requisite passphrase.

Until enchome is mounted, /home will be drawn from the system partition, and I want to maintain this with the same structure as enchome but without the sensitive data. So I want the same user directories, same hidden '.' files such as .bashrc, directories such as .ssh etc.

My question is, while enchome is mounted at /home, how can I sync the /home directory in the system partition from the same data in enchome, the problem being that enchome is now mounted at /home over the top of the system partition's /home. How can I get read/write access to the 'hidden' /home that is on the system partition without unmounting enchome, which I don't want to do?

Filesystems are ext[34], although I could use a different fs for enchome if it would help.

Comment: You don't.  This wouldn't work, you need to re-think your approach.

Comment: Put your sensitive data in its own directory, mounted at `/home/.secure/` or `/mnt/secure/` or some other location perhaps.

Comment: Thanks guys, I want to keep encrypted info at /home but it seems I need to find a slightly different way of achieving my overall objective.